# Cannot launch Xamarin.iOS app on device

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing an iPad application with Xamarin.iOS and MVVMcross. So I have a PCL with my View-Model and my Model, and an iOS project with the view. I use Visual Studio.

Before, I used Xamarin.iOS 6.3.6 beta version, and when I tried to launch the app on the device, an .app file was created and getting it with my Ipad, I could launch the application (impossible to launch directly from Visual Studio).

Yesterday, I uploaded Xamarin.iOS to 6.4.1. On simulator, everything's okay. When I try to launch the application on device, now the app is directly installed but the build stop and the following error appear in the debug output :

```
Failed to load AOT module '<my PCL>' while running in aot-only mode: doesn't match assembly.
```

And if I click on my app icon on the device,a black screen appear and disappear immediately.

Does someone know why this error appear?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This looks like something was cached somewhere or not updated correctly.

Here are a few ideas to try:

- Delete the app from the device.
- Clean & Rebuild your app.
- Build & install from Xamarin Studio on your Mac.
- Copy the Debug configuration to a new configuration (DebugTest for instance), and run that configuration instead.

Comment: Then I suggest you file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with your project so we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 8):

I regularly get the same issue here.

The workaround that I use is to switch the platform in the Visual Studio build Configuration Manager to "iPhoneSimulator", run a quick debug session on that, then switch the platform back to "iPhone", and the problem disappears for a while.

Unfortunately I have no intelligent reason as to why this works.  It seems to be doing a better job of the "Clean and Rebuild".

Comment: The same worked for me on macOS 10.12.5 with Visual Studio for Mac 7.1 build 583.

Answer (score 3):

After reading [a similar bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13743), I found that clearing the mtbs folder on the OS X host which is located at `$HOME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/` fixes this problem for me.

I have to do it so frequently I just have a PuTTY session open on my Windows box to clear the folder. I do hope that Xamarin fixes this issue soon.

Comment: After updating to the latest version of the software, I no longer have to do this.

Comment: I didn't have this path with Xamarin Studio 5.5.4, but I have a directory that looked very similar at `~/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-5.0/DerivedData/`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure Linker Behaviour is set to `Don't Link`

Clean, rebuild, remove old version from app.

Worked for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after I upgraded to XCode 5/iOS7. I noticed a warning that I hadn't installed XCode Command Line Tools. After I did that I rebuilt the application and it now runs.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and got it to work again by opening the Apple project properties and changing the provisioning profile identity from "Distribution" to "Developer".

Answer (score 0):

My workaround on Mac is to

1. Close Solution in XS
2. Quit XS. Command-Q
3. Reopen it and reopen solution.

After that it usually works again.