# Xcode: Failed to load AOT module 'Assembly-CSharp' while running in aot-only mode

Tags: xcode, .net-assembly, aot

I am attempting to publish from Unity to my iPhone 4s. The builds are successful, but I continue to get this message:

"Failed to load AOT module 'Assembly-CSharp' while running in aot-only mode because a dependency cannot be found or it is out of date."

When I attempt to run the app on my phone, it loads the Unity splash screen and then crashes out.

I have searched and searched for answers on this issue. I have tried rebooting (computer and device), reinstalling (all software), rolling back (all software), building to new locations on my computer, cleaning, making memory available, tinkering with build options...and yet I am having no success.

I am running: 
xcode 4.6.3
unity 3.5.7
iOS 6.1.3

Any advice I could get on this maddening issue would be appreciated!

Comment: I assume this issue has various assemblies involved - I came across this SO post while looking for `Failed to load AOT module 'System.Net.Http' while running in aot-only mode`

Answer (score 3):

For me uninstalling the app from device and doing clean and build solved the issue

Comment: To be clear, if you are getting this error via a Visual Studio/Xamarin build, you need to select the `Release` profile before running the clean - Clean all only cleans the currently selected profile (which caused me some lost time since I was cleaning the `Debug` profile, but of course Archiving uses the Release config)

Comment: It was not until I uninstalled it worked, I did several clean and build first. But I had aot error occurring suddenly and it was never related no any particular dependency

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Xamarin tools? I had the same issue and this solved it believe it or not...

The workaround is to switch to "iPhoneSimulator", run a quick debug session on that, then switch the platform back to "iPhone", and the problem disappears for a while.

[Cannot launch Xamarin.iOS app on device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19083725/855090)