# The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0) when debugging iOS from VS

Tags: ios, visual-studio, mono, xamarin

I have a problem that when I try to debug my iOS app with VS2013 (with Xamarin) I get the following error:

> The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I am aware of the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995263/cannot-launch-xamarin-ios-app-on-device). Cleaning the solution does solve the problem but then the next time I debug I need to do it again...

Would really appreciate if someone has a long term solution.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the device log?

Answer (score 0):

Is it crashing during launch? You've only got 10 seconds to launch and complete the FinishLaunching method in the AppDelegate, otherwise iOS terminates the app. This restriction doesn't apply in the simulator. If you've got a breakpoint in code that is running in this 10 second window, there's a very high likelihood that the app will be terminated unless you're very quick to continue.
I've also found that having breakpoints set anywhere in the app can add a few seconds to the launch time while the debugger hooks everything up. If your app is big or uses a framework like MvvmCross (which can take several seconds to initialise), you can be in a position where every millisecond helps.
If you can, let the app launch, then set any breakpoints. But if you're trying to debug your startup code, that's far from easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Visual Studio Android Emulator: have you tried check "Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version" in Hyper-V?

I got this trick from here [Fix for Could Not Connect To Debugger](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.dk/2016/02/fix-for-could-not-connect-to-debugger.html)